# "had + Subject + past participle" in conditionals

Tags: conditionals, ellipsis

I always thought that the elliptical conditional clause "Had + Subject + past participle" is used **only** in counterfactual conditionals, e.g. :

> Had Joe seen Mary, he would have fallen in love with her.

Recently, however, a number of native speakers said the boldfaced part in the following is okay:

> We retreated to the car while Marco kept apologizing for the rudeness of the twins to our hosts, whose gazes were now anything but friendly, **had they ever been**.

I'm confused. The above is **not a counterfactual sentence**. Can "had + subject + past participle" be used in **non**-counterfactual conditional sentences? Do those native speakers (NS) have a poor grasp of conditionals?

For some examples of how NS find it okay in non-counterfactual conditionals, see [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Should-had-they-ever-been-or-if-they-had-ever-been-be-used-in-the-following-We-retreated-to-the-car-while-Marco-kept-apologizing-for-the-rudeness-of-the-twins-to-our-hosts-whose-gazes-were-now-anything-but-friendly), and the reply by Mike Pattison.

> Your sentence seems unnecessarily complicated, but your question is about choosing between two conditional clauses and on that basis alone, either is acceptable. Personally, I would have said “if ever they had been” as sounding perhaps more natural, but that’s possibly a distinction without a difference.

From [The Free Dictionary Language forum](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst220921_had-they-ever-been.aspx),  the reply by FounDit.

> Yes, it's correct, but I'd say it's also very formal wording. It conveys the idea that the hosts never truly had friendly gazes, and they certainly were not at the point of leaving.

And https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/apologizing-for-the-rudeness-of-the-twins-to-our-hosts.3994987/ , see post #5, where Cagey says the sentence is "fine."

But then there is at least one native speaker who thinks the sentence in question is wrong:

See [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330210/had-they-ever-been?noredirect=1#comment624408_330210), where Michael Harvey says, "It's wrong, it's bad. That's all. Replace with 'if they had ever been'" in the comments.

Comment: Natives of where? Twitterland? If you are learning English following some sort of book, I suggest you post on English Language Learners. It may not fit into your category, but "had they ever been SO" is recognizable to me as English usage.

Comment: @David Here, https://www.quora.com/Should-had-they-ever-been-or-if-they-had-ever-been-be-used-in-the-following-We-retreated-to-the-car-while-Marco-kept-apologizing-for-the-rudeness-of-the-twins-to-our-hosts-whose-gazes-were-now-anything-but-friendly , see thre reply by Mike Pattison.

Comment: @David and here, https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst220921_had-they-ever-been.aspx , see the reply by FounDit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My question is whether "had + Subject + past participle" as a condition is limited to counterfactuals.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The issue is not whether the usage is outdated, but whether the usage is okay in non-counterfactual sentences.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Yes, your last sentence nails it. _The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_ has a sub-section in its discussion on the conditionals called _The don't know implicature: the speaker doesn't know whether P and Q are true or false_. I upvoted question because I found it interesting.

Comment: @Shoe I'm upset to see the question closed just because people are unwilling to read it carefully and recognize the issue.

Comment: I have voted to reopen the question. I will let others decide whether or not it should be migrated to ELL. But in my opinion, this is the right site.

Comment: You're a stubborn person aren't you? You could have saved a lot of time and bother by including the research in your original question in the first place. Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: Here, I'd interpret this sentence as the speaker doubting whether their glances were ever friendly. And I'd say that this is close enough to a counterfactual that you can use the structure there.

Comment: @Shoe: My "migrate" vote has been cancelled by the re-opening, but I don't have a strong opinion re ELL/ELU anyway, so it doesn't matter to me that I can't vote again.

Comment: This is a better question than the one you posted in December: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/330210/had-they-ever-been If I were you, I would delete it  before someone decides to close *this* question as a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with Michael Harvey -- the sentence is wrong and bad!

Comment: I agree with MH too. It's terrrrible. And "a number of native speakers said the boldfaced part": did they really? Not believable I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring any awkward or unnaturalness to the wording, if this is correct English:

- Had they ever been friendly, our hosts' gazes were now anything but, as we retreated to the car while Marco kept apologizing for the rudeness of the twins.

Then the originally quoted inversion of it should be correct too:

> We retreated to the car while Marco kept apologizing for the rudeness of the twins to our hosts, whose gazes were now anything but friendly, had they ever been.

Comment: I find the original sentence unacceptable, and Ray's recasting of it barely more acceptable.

Comment: @ColinFine, as I said, "*Ignoring any awkward or unnaturalness to the wording …*". I'm claiming only that it is grammatically acceptable.

Comment: Maybe we could try to find established examples in literature to prove the "had they ever been" is correct. So far I haven't found any.

Comment: @Apollyon, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had+they+ever+been+.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) shows "had they ever been ." as quickly rising in use since 1980.  But it's still only about 5% of the same phrase without the period.

Comment: @RayButterworth But those cases of "had they ever been" are not **non**-counterfactual conditional usages. We're investigating it as a **non**-counterfactual conditional, aren't we?

Answer (score 0):

The use of "Had + Subject + Past Participle" in English conditionals, particularly outside the classic counterfactual (unreal or hypothetical situations) contexts, can indeed seem confusing at first glance. Let's explore this with the structure you like.

**Understanding the Structure:**
Counterfactual Conditionals: Typically, "Had + Subject + Past Participle" is used for situations that didn't happen but are being imagined. For example, "Had Joe seen Mary, he would have fallen in love with her" imagines a scenario that didn't occur.

**Expanding Usage:**
Reflective or Speculative Use: The example you provided, "We retreated to the car...had they ever been," is a bit different. It uses the structure to reflect or speculate on the past in a nuanced way, almost like pondering aloud about the nature of the hosts' gazes. This isn't a classic conditional scenario but rather a reflective or rhetorical use of the structure.

**Native Speaker Views:**
Diverse Opinions: As highlighted by your research, opinions among native speakers (and experts) vary. Some find it acceptable and a matter of stylistic choice, suggesting it's formal or literary. Others prefer a more straightforward construction like "if they had ever been," considering it clearer or more natural.

**Key Points:**
**Formality and Style**: The use of "Had + Subject + Past Participle" in non-counterfactual sentences can be seen as formal or literary, adding a layer of sophistication or reflection to the sentence.

**Context and Clarity**: Whether this structure is appropriate may depend on the context and the desired clarity or effect in communication.

**Conclusion**:
Yes, "Had + Subject + Past Participle" can be used outside strict counterfactual conditionals, particularly in reflective or speculative contexts. While some may debate its clarity or naturalness, it's a stylistic choice that can convey subtlety and depth in the right circumstances. Understanding and appreciating this flexibility can enrich your engagement with English, showcasing the language's breadth and depth.